# Array stored in a linked list. (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, data-structures, linked-list

Is it possible to store a whole array as a node in a linked list. I am using the Linked List collection java provides and I keep getting an error for the following code.

```
List<Object[]> params = new LinkedList<Object[]>(); 
params.add(new Object[] { "ahhsjhs", {"jsdjdsk","djksdjsdk"}, true});
```

Type mismatch: cannot convert from String[] to Object

Comment: Do you mean `params.add(new Object[]{"ahhsjhs", new String[]{"jsdjdsk", "djksdjsdk"}, true});` but are you sure you want this structure of data, I would suggest to use classes to store this type of data!

Comment: No I would like this structure of data. And yes that is what i mean

Comment: It would help if we knew what error you get...

Comment: The corrected code by @YCF_L just works, try this:
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Object[]> params = new LinkedList<Object[]>();
    params.add(new Object[] { "ahhsjhs", new String[]{"jsdjdsk","djksdjsdk"}, true});
    System.out.println(params);
  }

Comment: You did not declared this: "{"jsdjdsk","djksdjsdk"}" right as you didn't specify what is this so the compiler can't understand what object to put there, i would assume you want this as: "new String[]{"jsdjdsk","djksdjsdk"}"

Answer (score 1):

You can use this and not get error

```
List<Object[]> params = new LinkedList<Object[]>(); 
params.add(new Object[]{"ahhsjhs", new String[]{"jsdjdsk", "djksdjsdk"}, true});
```

You can even do this and there is nothing wrong

```
List<Object[]> params = new LinkedList<Object[]>(); 
params.add(new Object[]{"ahhsjhs", new Object[]{new Object[] {"@@", new Object[] {"@@"},"@@"}, "@@"}, true});
```

But it is bad practice! You should approach to OOP.

Answer (score 0):

Just put this `String[] objects`:

```
List<Object[]> params = new LinkedList<Object[]>();
String[] objects = new String[] { "jsdjdsk", "djksdjsdk" };
params.add(new Object[] { "ahhsjhs", objects, true });
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, and you're doing it (almost) correctly. Compiler get confused with the inline declaration, doing the declaration outside should get you past the error, something like the following:

```
        List<Object[]> params = new LinkedList<Object[]>();
        String[] a = new String[]{"jsdjdsk","djksdjsdk"};
        params.add(new Object[] { a });
        params.add(new Object[] { "ahhsjhs", true});
        System.out.println(params);
    }
```

This with java:8.